# Display All ().html in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Sorry for the lack of description in title, it's difficult to explain.

So I have a simple signup page and I made a bunch of functions in my code that check things such as the username length, make sure the passwords match, etc..

The problem is, if there is more than one error in the users input, it only displays one error at the bottom.

HEre is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCBradley3k/xqcJS/19/

Javascript:

```
$('#join').on('click', function () {

    var correct = true;

    $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').each(function (indx) {
        var $currentField = $(this);
        if ($currentField.val() === '') {
            $currentField.addClass('empty');
            correct = false;
            $currentField.one('keydown', function () {
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');
            });
        } else {
            $currentField.removeClass('empty');
        }


    });

    function userLength() {
        var x = $('input[name="user"]').val();
        if (x.length < 6) {
            $('#answer').html('Less than six characters.');
            $('input[name="user"]').addClass('empty');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function passwordCheck() {
        var x = $('input[name="password"]').val();
        var y = $('input[name="passwordcheck"]').val();
        if (x === y) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#answer').html('Two different passwords');
            $('input[name="password"], input[name="passwordcheck"]').addClass('empty');
            return false;
        }

    }


    function validateForm() {
        var x = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        if (x.indexOf('@') !== -1 && x.lastIndexOf(".") !== -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#answer').html('Not a valid email');
            $('input[name="email"]').addClass('empty');
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (correct) {
        if (userLength()) {
            if (passwordCheck()) {
                if (validateForm()) {

                    $('#answer').html('Thank You!');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.inputs').hide("slide", {
                            direction: "up"
                        }, 1000);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#answer').html('Please fill highlighted fields.');
    }
});
```

You can see that all of them edit the #('#answer') div with .html(). But only one is displayed when there is more than one error. Once that error is fixed and the button is pressed, it will then display the next error. I want them all to be displayed in a list.

Comment: Add the errors to an array and replace the HTML with the items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgANS/1/) that may be of some help. The idea is to create an array with the errors in it like so:

```
var errors = [];
errors.push("Error 1");
errors.push("Error 2");
```

As you step through the validation, every time an error is encountered you simply `push` the error string onto the array. When you get to the end of the validation you need to compile these errors into html like that can be appended to your `$('#answer')` element. In this case the items are compiled into an unordered list. You can change this to fit your needs.

```
var content = "<ul>";
for(var a = 0, len = errors.length; a < len; a++) {
    content += "<li>" + errors[a] + "</li>";   
}
content += "</ul>";
$('#answer').html(content);
```

The html is built dynamically and stored in the variable `content`. `content` is then appended to your html element that displays the errors (in your case `answer`).

Comment: The problem is, all of my errors are in separate functions. I don't really see how I could access all of them and post them together.

Comment: Right under `var correct = true;` create an array like `var errors = [];`. By creating inside the `click` function but outside of the individual functions you will have access to the array as it will remain in scope until you leave the `click` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues with doing what you want.

First, you are only continuing your checks if the first one passes, due to your nested `if` statements.

Second, you are replacing the `#answer` html with the message, which means even if you do each check, you will only see the results of the last one.

A simple fix would be to un-nest your if statements, and keep a variable that tracks the overall pass state.  Secondly, instead of using `.html()`, use `.append()`, but make sure to clear out `#answer` before starting your checks.

```
correct &= checkFilled();
correct &= userLength();
correct &= passwordCheck();
correct &= validateForm();

if (correct) {
    // ...
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9cFKW/

Note: I made your form filled check it's own function to work better with this method.

You can do some more fancy things, like pushing error messages on an array, and then checking the array for errors at the end and appending all of the messages, but this should get you started.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the help. Just one more thing. When everything is left blank, I get all  the errors, instead of just fill highlighted fields. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Yes, but it depends what you want.  So, do you want it to not check *anything* until all of the fields are filled?  Or do you want it to only check a particular field if it's not blank?

Comment: Here is a version that checks to make sure the fields are filled first, then does the checking.  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9cFKW/1/

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning so much from these little edits. That partially solved my problem though. For example, when a field is left blank, I don't want to know that it is blank, and it's not long enough. I also wanted it to display the errors of filled boxes. So if I had the form and a box is not filled in, it would say it's not filled in and if there was another box that was filled in but had an error, it would also tell me that error at the same time. Kind of hard to explain.

Comment: In your current configuration, you would need to check for empty in your `if-then-else` statements inside of each check function.  Before I go too far, I should note that there are plugins to do all of this validation, such as http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/